# Laravel Foreach sum result with while filter

Tags: laravel, foreach

**Here my table**

:chart_of_account_category

id

name

:chart_of_accounts

id

chart_of_accounts_category_id

:ledger_book

id

transaction_id

chart_of_accounts_id

:transaction

id

name

date

total

[this is what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB47g.png)

**Controller**

```
$chart_of_accounts_category = ChartOfAccountsCategory::get();
return view ('backend.ledger_book.index', compact('chart_of_accounts_category'));
```

**Blade/View**

```
@foreach ($chart_of_accounts_category as $account_category )
   @foreach ($account_category->ChartOfAccounts as $item)
     $item->LedgerBook->where('chart_of_accounts_id', $item->id)->sum('transaction.total'), 2)
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

i can get the sum thru this, but i still need to filter few things more, which i done it in blade. but cant get the filter works properly especially where like with symbol %, i would minimize query inside blade, is there anywhere i can get the result thru controller?

```
$item->LedgerBook->where('chart_of_accounts_id', $item->id)->where('transaction.date', 'like', '2019-06-%')->sum('transaction.total'), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'like' operator, you can use
`->whereYear('transaction.date', '2019')->whereMonth('transaction.date', '06')`.

---

Also, I would suggest you to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `ChartOfAccounts`, `LedgerBook` and `Transaction` in your Controller. This will make your `foreach` loops much faster.

```
$chart_of_accounts_category = ChartOfAccountsCategory::with(['chartOfAccounts' => function ($query) { 
  $query->with(['ledgerBooks' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(‘transaction’)
      ->whereHas(‘transaction', function ($query) {
        $query->whereYear('date', '2019')
          ->whereMonth('date', '06');
      });
  }]); 
}])
  ->get();
```

Comment: ->whereYear('transaction.date', '2019')->whereMonth('transaction.date', '06') only can be use in controller right?
what about Eager load with Transaction table? how can i achieve that?

Comment: Yes, you can also eager load transactions. I updated my answer to show this.
I would use whereMonth and whereYear in the Controller, but you can probably use them in views also

Comment: $chart_of_accounts_category = ChartOfAccountsCategory::with(['ChartOfAccounts' => function ($query) { 
            $query->with(['LedgerBook' => function ($query) {
              $query->with('Transaction')->where('date', 'like', '2019-06-%');
            }]); 
        }])
        ->get();
seems working, but when come to filtering, it cant find proper table.

Comment: $chart_of_accounts_category = ChartOfAccountsCategory::with(['ChartOfAccounts' => function ($query) use($filter_year, $filter_month) { 
            $query->with(['LedgerBook' => function ($query) use($filter_year, $filter_month) {
                $query->with(['Transaction' => function ($query) use($filter_year, $filter_month) {
                    $query->where('date', 'like', $filter_year.'-'.$filter_month.'%')->where('business_id', session()->get('business_id'));
                  }]); 
            }]); 
        }])
        ->get();
solved it by this query, thanks a lot there mate

Comment: @MohammadIskandar good job! You’re welcome. Note that you can upvote and accept my answer so others who might come to this question know that this was the solution.

Comment: any idea why filtering not works? issit because of 'with'?

Comment: @MohammadIskandar try using ->whereHas on transaction relationship, after with. I updated my answer with this